Interpreting Mass-Volume as an evaluation criterion for unsupervised anomaly detection
I have found this paper How to Evaluate the Quality of Unsupervised Anomaly Detection Algorithms? by
Nicolas Goix that talks about evaluation of unsupervised anomaly scoring functions by the use of what the author calls Mass-Volume and Excess-Mass. I have also found the code from the paper here, which is quite handy. I am focusing on M-V and I am trying to interpret the meaning and why does it make sense.
Mass-Volume is described as follows:
$$
MV_{s}(\alpha) = \inf_{u \geq 0} Leb(s(\mathbf{U}) \geq u) ~~~ s.t. ~~~ \mathbb{P}(s((\mathbf{X})) \geq u) \geq \alpha
$$
where
$\alpha$ is a cumulative mass 
$s$ is some anomaly scoring function 
$\mathbf{X}$ is our feature set with dimensions (N,M)
$\mathbf{U}$ is a randomly generated multivariate uniform variable which takes as lower boundary $\inf(\mathbf{X})$ and upper boundary $\sup(\mathbf{X})$. This essentially creates a rectangle spanning from the minimum feature value to the maximum feature value.
$u$ is a quantile at which we are evaluating the Lebesgue measure denoted as $Leb$.
In implementation in Python, this looks like this:
clf = SomeAnomalyScoringModel()


alpha_min = 0.9
alpha_max = 0.999
axis_alpha = np.arange(alpha_min, alpha_max, 0.0001)


lim_inf = X.min(axis=0)
lim_sup = X.max(axis=0)
n_generated = 100000
unif = np.random.uniform(lim_inf, lim_sup,
                            size=(n_generated, n_features))
volume_support = (lim_sup - lim_inf).prod()


s_unif = clf.decision_function(unif)  
s_x = clf.decision_function(X) 


def mass_volume(axis_alpha, volume_support, s_unif, s_X, n_generated):
    n_samples = s_X.shape[0]
    s_X_argsort = s_X.argsort()
    mass = 0
    cpt = 0
    u = s_X[s_X_argsort[-1]]
    mv = np.zeros(axis_alpha.shape[0])
    for i in range(axis_alpha.shape[0]):
        while mass < axis_alpha[i]:
            # looking for u here
            cpt += 1
            u = s_X[s_X_argsort[-cpt]]
            mass = 1. / n_samples * cpt  # sum(s_X > u)
        mv[i] = float((s_unif >= u).sum()) / n_generated * volume_support
    return auc(axis_alpha, mv), mv

I have a rough idea of what is happening here. By sorting $s(x)$, we are looking for its quantile $u$ given $\alpha$ by adding $mass$ until we have reached the desired $\alpha$-mass. When we have done that, we stop, since we have reached the constraint $\mathbf{P}(s(\mathbb{X})\geq q) \geq \alpha$. At that point, we calculate $Leb(s(\mathbf{U})\geq u)$. And we repeat for all desired $\alpha$ levels.
Two questions from here:
How can we interpret this? My best explanation is that we treat the scoring function $s$ as a uniform distribution (which by design has no outliers) and measuring its cumulative density as proxied by Lebesgue measure (so, just area in this case) once we have reached the tail of our real scoring distribution. But how does this show that $s$ is a good model?
Why is Lebesgue defined as float((s_unif >= u).sum()) / n_generated * volume_support?
This is equivalent of the volume of a rectangular box when the uniform variable when greater the $u$, so is it then a bivariate cumulative density? What is this?

Short answers, since nobody seems to have replied:

You ask if "s is a good model." Being pedantic: s is not a model at all - it is a scoring function. As to what makes it good, I don't see the answer in this paper. However, they reference the paper in which this object was first defined: https://proceedings.mlr.press/v31/clemencon13a.pdf. You can see in that paper that s is meant to allow you to find a ranking of "outlier-ness" of your observations that should be "close" to the rank-order of the PDF evaluated at the point (where PDF is evaluated with respect to Lebesgue measure, which is why Lebesgue measure shows up at all). That is, you want to find a ranking $\sigma$ so that $\sigma(i) > \sigma(j)$ if and only if $f(X_{\sigma(i)}) > f(X_{\sigma(j)})$, where $f$ is the density of your random variable with respect to Lebesgue measure. It is up to you whether this sort of ranking is "good" or not, and also up to you if you think the estimate of this ranking if "good" or not (we know that this problem is in general very difficult in high dimensions). It certainly has a lot of obvious "flaws" - for example, like many unsupervised methods, it isn't even close to being invariant under reparameterization - but it might be what you want in your specific application. I'd suggest reading the paper that introduces the measure, which does a very good job of explaining what the measure is doing (and thus, by omission, what sorts of outliers it is not interesting in catching).

The first part, float((s_unif >= u).sum()) / n_generated, is a Monte Carlo estimate of the probability that a uniform random variable is larger than u (if n_generated were "equal to infinity," it would be exactly this probability); that is, this part is 1-(CDF of s(uniform random variable) evaluated at u). The second part, 1/volume_support, is the density of a uniform random variable with respect to Lebesgue measure; multiplying by this density converts from a measure under uniform to a measure under Lebesgue.


